# Is there anyway to get a consistent dark mode look across Linux browsers?

Tags: linux, browser, dark-mode

I use and have open several different browsers on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04)

I would like to have a consistent dark mode UI across all of them. But when I try to reproduce the same UI using the same settings I use with Chrome on Opera, Firefox, Vivaldi, Brave and Chromium I am unable to achieve the look I'd prefer.

My reference look is Chrome and the way it looks in a dark mode (following GTK theme)

[Chrome Dark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDZ8q.png)

It has GTK window decorations, including webpage title, and a consistenly dark look

But in all the other browsers the UI is not quite the same:

- Opera [Opera Dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSkof.png) (no GTK window controls, CSD decorations and puts tabs on the title bar)
- Chromium [Chromim Dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdSbc.png)  ( GTK host window controls, tabs separated from title bar, but parts of the UI are still not dark
- Vivaldi [Vivaldi Dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNJvM.png) ( no GTK controls, CSD not dark, tabs on the title bar)
- Firefox [Firefox Dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUI7t.png)  (tabs on the window title bar)
- Brave [Brave Dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLZZt.png)  (tabs on the window title bar)

Aditionally, while all browsers correctly use dark mode for new blank page and also for menus, in Chromium that doesnt happen at all: [Chromium not dark in new tab and menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6hxV.png)

I tried different configurations, dark themes, extensions that force dark mode to no avail.

I think it all comes down to:

- how to disable CSD and force the use of native window controls (GTK)
- how to stop tab separators on the window title bar
- how to get Chromium to look like Chrome dark theme

As I said, I already tried several configurations but got nowhere. Any hints on how to solve this are welcome! :-)

Comment: https://mybrowseraddon.com/dark-mode.html, works fine for firefox in ubuntu20

Comment: I'm not looking to apply dark mode to webpages I am looking to apply (consistent) dark mode theme to the browser itself.